# Call IBM RFT Script by Java code from eclipse

Tags: java, rft

> I am calling IBM RFT script from Java program, RFT part is working
>   fine,but I want to call RFT script from Java program.

```
public class CallRFT 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String rftplaybackArgs[] = new String[]{"-datastore", "C:/Users/aksrivastav/Workspace_Rational/Project1", "-playback", "CROI_TestCases_SearchCompanyByName"};



        try
        {
        Thread.sleep(100);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}

        System.out.println("I got .. + " + rftplaybackArgs.toString());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft.main(rftplaybackArgs);




    }



}
```

> After executing program i am getting this error **Script Playback Failure:
>   CRFCN0379E: Load script class failed
>   [CROI_TestCases_SearchCompanyByName]
>   [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   CROI_TestCases_SearchCompanyByName]**

Comment: working now...i was missing package name..

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to run as follows:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

public void run() 
{
    System.out.println("Executing script ");

    String[] cmdarray = {"\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe\"","-jar", "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\FunctionalTester\\bin\\rational_ft.jar\"","-datastore","C:\\RFTWorkspaces\\InhouseProject\\ProjectOne","-playback","Inhouse"};
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}